# Stateless Token Auth security

Tags: rest, security, web-applications, django-rest-framework

I'm new to ReST and am implementing a ReSTful token authentication, trying to use Django-Rest-Framework JWT, in a mobile web app in the standard way

- client sends credentials
- server verifies and sends token and expiration date back. Deletes token from db
- client calls refresh token when user makes request and token is about to expire
- on client request, server verifies token signature
- on expired token mobile app logs user out. Mobile app checks expiration not server

I decided to make the mobile app check the expiration date since I read that is ReSTFul, and the server checking it requires it to store tokens which is not ReSTful

I have a few security questions regarding the above implementation:

1) Doesn't obtaining one token give the attacker complete access to the user's login no matter how many token refreshes happen?

Even if it's over https, let's say by some means a token was retrieved by an attacker, i.e. ssl interceptor proxy.Obviously the mobile application won't allow them to login, but they can grab data by calling the api with the token through any HTTP client.

2) What is the purpose of having refreshing tokens in the first place if the server considers all of them as valid?

There seems to be no forward security in this.However, if the server stored the tokens and kept their expiration dates, a complete user compromise would be stopped, but not a per session compromise. Obviously with an SSL interceptor they could still compromise the user, but would need to catch every login. However that implementation  is not ReSTful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, expired tokens are valid tokens, but you can check if token expired or not, before taken any action, and reject the ones expired. There are several things you can do to increase the security of your app:

- You can add the hashed password inside token. Therefore if user lost his/her mobile, when password changed in another device, you can reject the tokens with old password hash.
- This one is not totally restful, but not that bad as well: you can add a table called revokedTokens in db which keeps track of id of tokens (obviously you should add it to token) user revoked, if you receive request with that token later on, you can reject it until it expires. when it expires you can remove from the table, as expired tokens won't be a problem anyway.
- You can add the device's host name when user logs in to the token, and compare it with the request's host name, to have additional layer of security for ssl interceptor attack. Yes, it's not total protection, but still a bit better, as attacker needs to change his/her host name in addition to sending the token from another device.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How exactly can you reject JWT token when user changed his password (or any other field used to generate the JWT)? JWT validation is done only from the data in JWT and as far as the JWT is not expired its signature will be valid even if the user password in your database was changed.

Comment: @LaurynasMališauskas when you receive the token from the client, which has the hashed password in it when you were sending, just check that hash with the password hash in your database, if they're not the same, return error to the client.

Comment: This is not exactly the point of JWT as it should be self contained token. However i did some research and it seems a lot of people use it just like an opaque tokens would be used.